# xcode 7 runs correct with iphone 6 simulator, but not with real device

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode7, iphone-6, uiscreen

`[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]` returning 568 for real iPhone 6 device.

When I use iPhone6 simulator, I get the correct value of 667.

I set all the launch images and icons in the assets catalog for all ios versions (and simulator works just fine). Did all the cleaning, deleted the previous version from the device and even tried to change the images names.
But I keep getting the iPhone5 dimensions for iPhone6 device.